# Drawing only visible region of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an custom edittext which may contain large  input text expanding over 1000 line. When the content of edittext is very large, the scrolling starts getting slow. This is due to loop in my overrided draw method. This method uses getlinecount method and perform painting over all the lines of edittext. It is possible only to paint the visible region of edittext thus reducing the loop complexity?

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {
    private Rect mRect;
    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int height = getHeight();
        int lineHeight = getLineHeight();
        int count = height / lineHeight;
        if (getLineCount() > count)
            count = getLineCount();

        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, mRect);//first line

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            //some operation for each line.
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added my inherited edit class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using getScrollX() and thus finding out the only the visible region.

Comment: Ahh. This is what I've been looking far all this time.